# Create category column mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a transactions table,

```
Id customer_id order_id   transaction_date    status    vendor
1  BOB         TEST000001 2020-01-01          SHIPPED   Vendor BRO
2  JESS        TEST000002 2020-01-01          CANCELLED Vendor BRO
3  KAREN       TEST000003 2020-01-03          CANCELLED Vendor ALPHA
4  JESS        TEST000004 2020-02-04          CANCELLED Vendor CHARLIE
```

I want to query it using MySQL 5.7 group by vendor and count number of transaction, and categorize vendor by these criteria

1. Great: More than 2 SHIPPED and 0 CANCELLED transactions
2. OK: More than 2 SHIPPED and 1 or more CANCELLED transactions
3. Mediocre: other than Superb and Good criteria

result should be like this,

```
Vendor     Category Total Transaction
Vendor BRO GREAT    3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a `case` expression in an aggregation query:

```
select vendor, count(*) as total_transaction,
       (case when sum(status = 'SHIPPED') > 2 and sum(status = 'CANCELLED') = 0
             then 'Great'
             when sum(status = 'SHIPPED') > 2 and sum(status = 'CANCELLED') > 0
             then 'OK'
             else 'Mediocre'
        end) as status
from t
group by vendor;
```

Comment: Thanks! Also, I'd like to sort it by the case..
I've done this so far, but it seems to be wrong.
ORDER BY CASE(category, 'Superb','Good','Normal');

Comment: @wingswingswings . . . I think you can use `order by field(category, 'Superb', 'Good', 'Normal')`.

Comment: Tried that, it gave me this message, any advise?Error Code: 1247. Reference 'category' not supported (reference to group function)

Comment: @wingswingswings . . . That should be status.

Comment: Thank you so much! You save my time!